# joomla fully customize component link

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I made a component and now I want to customize the link for it.
I already wrote the router.php.
The link to the component view (if I use the JRoute function of course) now looks good, except for the first part, which looks like :

http://www.example.com/en/component/componentname/...

don't mind the "en", it's there cause I use JomFish to manage more languages on my site.

I want to transform "/component/componentname/" to "/myString/" for example.

I can't use the menu for this, cause my site displays info from a database, linking this many sites to my menu is impossible.

The only solution I found requires the changing of the Joomla JRoute function (I found only a suggestion, not how it's done :( ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using mod_rewrite to rewrite your url?

Basically you put the rewrite rules into your .htaccess file and Apache will handle the rest.

There is a great guide that teaches you all about it on http://www.htmlist.com/how-to/a-simplemod_rewrite-tutorial/